# How to install a binstar package in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, pdfminer, binstar

I was unable to install -[pdfminer](http://euske.github.io/pdfminer/index.html)- using the source distribution so I was trying to use [binstar](https://binstar.org/jacksongs/pdfminer) to do so. Since I am using the Ananconda distribution of Python, I type:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jacksongs pdfminer
```

but, get the following error:

```
Fetching package metadata: ...
Error: No packages found in current win-32 channels matching: pdfminer
You can search for this package on Binstar with
binstar search -t conda pdfminer
```

Could you please suggest a solution?

Thank you.

PS: `binstar search -t conda pdfminer` returns the following:

```
Run 'binstar show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
                      Name | Access       | Package Types   | Summary
 ------------------------- | ------------ | --------------- | --------------------
           auto/pdfminer3k | published    | conda           |     
 http://bitbucket.org/hsoft/pdfminer3k
        jacksongs/pdfminer | public       | conda           | PDF parser and analyzer
 Found 2 packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has probably got to do with the choice of platform. Binstar only has a package for OS X 64 whereas I am using windows.

Comment: Yep, this is the issue. Unfortunately, the `binstar search` command does not show only packages for your platform, but for all platforms.

Comment: Is there anything to be done if you can't find an appropriate package for your platform? Python-naive question, I know, but is there a way to hack a Linux package so it works on Win? pdfrw is the specific one I'm trying to install, but perhaps pdfminer would work too.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have never used the anaconda distribution of python but judging by the information you have given, have you tried

`conda install -c http://bitbucket.org/hsoft/pdfminer3k`

Like I said before, I've never used this distribution and I have near to no idea of the solutions you have tried.

I hope I helped,

~Bobbeh

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following: (Anaconda Python 2.7 on Windows 10 64-bit)

This adds the conda-forge channel to your list of channels

`conda config --add channels cond`a-forge

Installs pdfminer

```
conda install pdfminer
```

This was my source: [conda-forge:pdfminer on github](https://github.com/conda-forge/pdfminer-feedstock)